# How can I get the color and translucency of the iOS 10 watch Navigation Bar?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I am looking to get the translucency and color of the iOS 10 watch navigation bar. I managed the color by color picking the RGB but I cannot figure out the translucency. I am using Swift 3, can anyone tell me how to get the translucency? I have circled what translucency I'm looking for.

Please provide the code if you can.

[image: picture]

Comment: Your post not very clear. are you trying to do in `iOS` or `watchOS`?.

Comment: Sorry about that, I mean iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below method to achieve `navigationBar translucent effect`. When `UIContentView` scrolls as the picture you posted.

**In viewDidLoad:**

```
  view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
  navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.blackTranslucent
  navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
```

**Updated**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

**Note:**

- Screen recording is not showing the real result.I recommend you to test the code in a real device.
- You can use the same method. If you developing `tabBar` based project.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to get rid of **translucent effect**, just

#### Programatically:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
```

#### In Storyboard:

Just click on the **navigation bar**, and in **attribute inspector**, you'll find it.

Comment: No, I want to get the translucent effect. I know it is translucent by default but it is not nearly as translucent as the picture that I posted, even though I got the color by color picking the navbar.