# How to make another view's colors bleed behind a navigation bar in iOS?

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, blur, uivisualeffectview

I saw an app that had a blurred bar with colors bleeding inside it, like this:

[image: navigation bar]

Unlike this screenshot however, apparently there wasn't an image directly behind the bar, only below.

It's like the bar was picking the colors from the view at the center, and blurring it. Any ideas on how could I achieve that?

Comment: Seems like a stock `UINavigationBar` with translucency (`isTranslucent = true`). Also, if you look closely, the colors are picked up by the top portions of the images being scrolled up (and behind the bar)...

Comment: Yeah I think I didn't express myself very well. Yes, in this screenshot the colors are being picked from the image behind the bar. But the thing is, is it possible to have the colors being picked from an image that is not being scrolled behind the bar?

Comment: I guess you could try putting a static view pinned to the top behind the navigation bar, but above your tableview/collectionview & compensate for its height by setting the contentInset accordingly (or pin the tableview at the bottom of this view)

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43419860/how-can-i-get-the-color-and-translucency-of-the-ios-10-watch-navigation-bar/43527133#43527133